# Test failing after adding then and catch to promise

Tags: javascript, promise, mocking, jestjs

I have the following (simplified for the sake of scoping down problem) code:

```
function pushPromises() {
  const promises = [];

  promises.push(firstPromise('something'))
  promises.push(secondPromise('somethingelse'))

  return promises;
}

export default handlePromises(async (c) => {
  const results = await Promise.all(pushPromises())
  c.success(results);
});
```

My test mocks those firstPromise and secondPromise to check if they were called with the right arguments. This works (assume mock set up is properly done):

```
jest.mock('src/firstPromise');
jest.mock('src/secondPromise');

describe('test', () => {
  let firstMock;
  let secondMock;


  beforeEach(() => {
    require('src/firstPromise').default = firstMock;
    require('src/secondPromise').default = secondMock;
  })

  it('test', async () => {
    await handlePromises(context);
    expect(firstPromiseMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(secondPromiseMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Now, if I add handlers to the promises such as:

```
function pushPromises() {
      const promises = [];

      promises.push(
        firstPromise('something')
        .then(r => console.log(r))
        .catch(e => console.log(e))
      )
      promises.push(
        secondPromise('somethingelse')
        .then(r => console.log(r))
        .catch(e => console.log(e))
      )

      return promises;
    }
```

The first expectation passes, but the second one doesn't. It looks like the second promise is no longer called.

How can I modify the test/code so that adding handlers on the promises don't make the test break? It looks like it is just finishing the execution on the first promise handler and does never get to the second one.

EDIT:

I have modified the function to return a Promise.all without await:

```
 export default handlePromises(async (c) => {
      return Promise.all(pushPromises())
 });
```

But I'm having the exact same issue. The second promise is not called if the first one has a `.then`.

Comment: How're those mocks set up?

Comment: `await handlePromises(context);`   handlePromises doesn't look like a promise to me, so the await will have no effect.

Comment: handlePromises(context) here context must have a callback named success and then you will have to move your expect statements in success callback.

Comment: You have two very different ways that you call `handlePromises`. In your real code, you call it with an async function and export its result, most likely a promise. In your test code, you are calling it with your context, which most likely is an object.

Comment: Added mock set up @raina77ow

Comment: @DanielHilgarth why would that explain that the expectations work if I don't add (then, catch) in my promises?

Comment: It doesn't really explain that. But that difference is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your handlePromises function accepts a callback but you are handling it as it returns a promise, it is not a good way to go but you can test your method using callback as following

Modify your Test as=>

```
it('test', (done) => {
    handlePromises(context);
    context.success = (results) => {
        console.log(results)
        expect(firstPromiseMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        expect(secondPromiseMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
        done();
    }
});
```

Or modify your code as =>

```
function pushPromises() {
  const promises = [];

  promises.push(firstPromise('something'))
  promises.push(secondPromise('somethingelse'))

  return promises;
}

export default handlePromises = (context) => {
  return Promise.all(pushPromises()).then((data) => context.success(data))
};

//with async
export default handlePromises = async (context) => {
  let data = await Promise.all(pushPromises());
  context.success(data)
};
```

Comment: Why does it work when I don't add the `then` and `catch`? And how is this solving that issue?

Comment: I already tried modifying my code to not use the context and instead returning Promise.all(pushPromises()) and I see the same issue. The second promise is not being called if I add a `then` in the first promise.

Comment: @HommerSmith  `returning Promise.all(pushPromises()) ` Could you show us that version, as that's the one that should work.   The `then` / `catch` should have no effect on the promise return.

Comment: It solves the issue by making you tests to wait for all the promises to get resolved first, I am not very sure How it worked without then block @HommerSmith

Comment: it must be export default handlePromises = () => {
      return Promise.all(pushPromises())
 });

@HommerSmith

Comment: AZ_ I will try with the first approach (done()) because I need that context in the code. Will come back to you. I don't understand if we are doing an await Promise.all(), wouldn't doing an await in the test make all the promises resolve before testing? Isn't that the purpose of doing await in the test?

Comment: await will wait for the promise to get resolved inside the same async function, but if you are calling that function from somewhere outside you will have to again await for that function, but in your code you are awaiting and then returning the resolved value in callback to rather chaining promise you will have to create the callback hell;

Comment: and also you can have the context but dont use it as callback, updated the code, @HommerSmith

Comment: Isn't that the same than doing const data = await Promise.all(pushPromises()); context.success(data)?

Comment: No because that does not make the method to return the promise you are making the callback async, not the method itself. you will have to add the async on method like handlePromises  = async (context) => {...await } @HommerSmith

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190697/discussion-between-hommer-smith-and-az).

Answer (score 1):

In your edit, your handlePromises is still not a promise..

Try the following. ->

```
it('test', async () => {
  await Promise.all(pushPromises());
  expect(firstPromiseMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(secondPromiseMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: Why do I even need to do this do? If in my code (not my edit) I'm already doing `const results = await Promise.all(pushPromises())` doesn't that guarantee that all promises will be run (from a test perspective)?

Comment: @HommerSmith  No, because your `handlePromises` is not a promise, so when you do `await handlePromises()` it's not going to wait.  And this explains why your test fails, as the first promise might have resolved by the time your first `expect` is called, but your second promise might still be pending when your second `expect` is called.

Comment: What I don't understand Keith is why this just happens when I introduce then and catch in my promises. Anyway, if I need to have that context (the edit would not be valid because I really need to return that context.success) how would I do it?

Comment: @HommerSmith  `when I introduce then and catch`  It's just a timing thing,.  Sometimes the Javascript engine might optimise away a next tick, but it's something you should never rely on, in fact I'm pretty sure in early implementations of promises it was guaranteed a next tick would fire.  I'm not sure what context is and why needed, but all you need to do is make sure `handlePromises()` returns as a promise as currently it's not.  Looking at `AZ_` where he's returning a promise with `promise.all` and piggy backing the then method to update the context looks like what your after.